# Is It Possible To Create A Cursor In WPF From a VisualBrush?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, visualbrush

I'm doing some Drag and Drop operations, and I want to use a visual copy of the element I'm dragging for the cursor. It's easy enough to get a VisualBrush of the element, but I have no idea how to turn this into a cursor.

I've read the [Jamie Rodriguez blog posts](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112155029/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx), but his solution isn't quite what I'm looking for because he essentially wires things up to a "global" GiveFeedback event (his DragSource). I'd rather just take the image from the VisualBrush and make that the cursor. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually (both in the example you linked and in [this example by Bea Stollnitz](https://web.archive.org/web/20120620222921/http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)) this is done with an `Adorner`.

If you really wanted to change the `Cursor` itself, you'd have to construct a .cur file in memory and stream it into the [`Cursor` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522864.aspx).  I've never done this and I don't recommend it, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Bea's solution is really nice. I'm going with that.